# I am trying to create a react app with typescript but I keep getting failed to compile on start

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, error-handling, eslint

I am trying to create a react app with `--template typescript` and I keep getting this error:

```
ERROR in Plugin "react" was conflicted between "package.json » eslint-config-react-app » C:\Users\JULIO\desktop\ts\my-ts\node_modules\eslint-config-react-app\base.js" and "BaseConfig » C:\Users\JULIO\Desktop\ts\my-ts\node_modules\eslint-config-react-app\base.js".

webpack 5.65.0 compiled with 1 error in 5303 ms
```

Comment: try installing a new react project with ```npx create-react-app my-app``` then add typescript with ```npm install --save typescript @types/node @types/react @types/react-dom @types/jest``` let me know what happens

Comment: i tried that, but it didn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

The path you cd'ed into from the terminal has different capitalization than the real path, see that one has "desktop" and the other "Desktop".

C:\Users\JULIO\desktop\ts\my-ts\node_modules\eslint-config-react-app\base.js
C:\Users\JULIO\Desktop\ts\my-ts\node_modules\eslint-config-react-app\base.js

You should check that when you cd into the directory, you use the same exact capitalization as the real path.

I had the same problem, and this is what solved it for me.